# Is "(gerund) among the (superlative) (noun)" missing a reference?

Tags: grammar

Can I say this?

> Working at Stevens & Son means designing among the most glamorous tablecloths in Eastern Europe.

I'm not entirely sure if *among the most glamorous* is not missing a reference. I guess, I could alternatively say:

> Working at Stevens & Son means designing tablecloths that are among the most glamorous in Eastern Europe.

But I tend to like the first version better because

- is more compact/to the point
- it makes *most glamorous* stand out more

Comment: The first version gives me the impression that I will be _surrounded_ by tablecloths if I work there. While this may be the case, it is not the message you want to convey :)

Comment: @oerkelens very valid point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

> Working at Stevens & Son means designing some of the most glamorous tablecloths in Eastern Europe.

The *some* saves the issues with *among*

Comment: To keep *among* maybe do this: "Working at Stevens & Son means designing tablecloths which are among the most glamorous in Eastern Europe."

Comment: Apart from changing that to which, your sentence is identical to the second version OP did not like

Answer (score 2):

If I really twist my brain around, I can *sort of* get where you were trying to go with the first sentence. Maybe. On the fourth try.

My initial (and second, and third, and if I'm not careful, my fifth and sixth) parsing of the sentence has the tablecloths as your coworkers.

Since that is presumably not what you're after, you either have to use something like your second construction, or you have to use a word that is less ambiguous than "among".

> Working at Stevens & Son means designing tablecloths which are among the most glamorous in Eastern Europe.
>
> Working at Stevens & Son means designing some of the most glamorous tablecloths in Eastern Europe.

Comment: Isn't your first example the same as OPs with a which instead of that (and identical to GEdgar 's comment on my post)? Your second example is identical to mine

Comment: @mplungjan: none of the answers that existed before I posted (including yours) said anything about the tablecloths-as-coworkers issue, which is why I felt compelled to post. Also, your answer doesn't explain *why* the change from "among" to "some of" is helpful.

Comment: Actually the very first comment did 8 hours ago. Anyway, just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @mplungjan: a comment is not an answer.

Comment: @Marthaª: appreciate your answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

In the first phrase the design worker is the one among something which in this case are tablecloths when he should be among other design workers, whereas in the second phrase it's clear that the tablecloths are the ones among other tablecloths, making it correct in my view.

Comment: It would be much easier to read your post if your used more punctuation instead of making us mentally out of breath with a sentence that went on and on and on without any fullstops to break it into smaller bits that were easier to digest. Also the second sentence is understood as being correct but OP does not like it much since it is a bit more convoluted than the first one which although wrong is shorter

Answer (score 0):

In my view your first sentence really lacks something. You write tablecloths but you mean producers of tablecloths. And you don't work among several  pruducers but only  for one  producer. And I would avoid the adjective glamorous. A film star may be glamorous but such an adjective is hardly appropriate for producers of textiles. Ìt sounds like exaggerated praise.

My suggestion would be:  Working  for X means designing for one of the renowned producers of tablcloths in Western Europe.